# Inherits from a class that inherits networkBehviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity-networking

I'm trying to inherit a class that in NetworkBehaviour but whenever I inherit the parent class(script) stop working.

I have tried this:

```
using UnityEngine;  
using UnityEngine.Networking;   

public class FireFighter : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {}
    private void Move()
    {}
    private void break()
    {}
} 

public class FireCaptain : FireFighter
{   
    public override void Move ()
    {
        base.Move();
        Debug.Log("The captainMoved.");     
    }
}
```

In brief, FireFighter script works well but whenever I inherit it, it stops working. I need some help here. How can I inherit a class that inherits Networkbehaviour.

Comment: Please read the info associated with tags before using them on your question, so that you can check you're not misusing them.

Comment: Also, can you define "stops working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be carefull with the naming of your methods! **[`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break)** is a keyword and should not be used as method name.

---

Then you defined

```
private void Move()
```

in your base class `FireFighter`

=> in `FireCaptain` you can not do

```
public override void Move ()
```

1. because it is not `virtual` or `abstract` so you can't use `override` at all.
2. even if it would be you can't change the scope (from `private` to `public`) in an override.
3. and since it is `private` in your subclass you don't even have access to call `base.Move();` since it can be called only by the implementing class itself.

---

So

To 2.) & 3.) If you want it to be `public` in the subclass it also has to be `public` already in the base class. Or you can use `protected` so only the base class and its inheritors have access.

To 1.) To be able to override a method in your subclass it either has to be `virtual` or `abstract`. So make it

- `virtual` if you want to have an implementation in the base class to define a default behaviour and make it only **optional** to override it E.g. like

  ```
  // subclasses don't have to implement and override
  // this method but can. Also the base.Move(); is optional
  public virtual void Move()
  {
      Debug.Log("You might want to override this to implement a movement");
  }
  ```
- `abstract` if you do not want to have an implementation in tha base class and want to **force** the subclasses to implement this e.g. like

  ```
  // subclasses will throw a compiler error if they
  // do not implement this method 
  // (without base.Move(); since hte base has no implementation)
  public abstract void Move();
  ```